# How can I cast an int to a Keycode in Unity? (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to loop through a group of Keycodes to check for any keyboard event, and forward the ascii or decimal value of the key upon each `GetKeyUp` and `GetKeyDown` events.

I tried this, but doesnt seem to work.

```
while (true)
{
    for (int count = 97; count < 123; count++)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(((char)count).ToString()))
        {
            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a correct way to write this, or is there some other more efficient method i'm missing that doesnt involve manually assigning an `int` to each key and modifier key?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Input.inputString`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-inputString.html) to get the characters entered in the current frame:

> **Input.inputString**
>
> Returns the keyboard input entered this frame. (Read Only)
>
> Only ASCII characters are contained in the `inputString`.
>
> The string can contain two special characters which should be handled:
>   Character `"\b"` represents backspace. Character `"\n"` represents return
>   or enter.

You can see an example of how to use it in the documentation link above.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for Unity, the Input.GetKeyDown() and Input.GetKeyUp() methods can take either a string or [KeyCode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html) as the parameter.  Use the KeyCode instead of casting to int.  It's much more readable and more portable.  If you are only looking for a set of keys, create an enum for just that set.  Then you can enumerate through that enum of just the keys that you are watching and call GetKeyDown() or GetKeyUp() and then return the key.

Something sort of like this (untested)?

```
public enum MyKeys
{
    KeyCode.Space,
    KeyCode.A,
    KeyCode.W,
    KeyCode.S,
    KeyCode.D
}

KeyCode CheckMyKey()
{
    foreach(var i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyKeys)))
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(i))
            return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is what you're doing, why would you use reflection? Just make an array/list.

Comment: It was just a POC to illustrate a point.  It would be far more efficient to use List<KeyCode> or an Array of Keycode.